# Tensorflow Serving and nosql database

Tags: nosql, tensorflow-serving

Hello I want to understand the architecture that can be developed if I have these three things:
(i)- A docker container using tensorflow serving
(ii)- A front-end website that calls this docker container for prediction.
(iii)- A SQL or nosql database that stores the logs.

Now I am able to understand how to set up and architecture using (i) and (ii) but I am not able to figure out how to connect the docker container having tensorflow serving with the database?

Answer (score 0):

This is a design /architecture issue. You have 3 components

1. UI 2) Model 3) DB store.

The logic for calling the model for inference and saving the result into a DB can be done only via the business layer of the UI component (orchestration layer).
The TF seving has no capability to hold the logic for saving the result in a data store as it is a pure rest API based utility.